# Resultados sem valor nas variáveis, os valores adicionados na classe TesteMain não estão sendo usados nos metodos da classe Calculadora

Tags: java, variáveis

```
public class Calculadora {
         
    public float valor1;
    public float valor2;
    public float valor3;
    
    public Calculadora(float valor1) {
        
    }
    
    public Calculadora(float valor1, float valor2){
        
    }
    
    public Calculadora(float valor1, float valor2, float valor3){
        
    }
 
    public float soma(){
        return valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    }
    
    public float subtracao(){
        return valor1 - valor2 - valor3;
    }
    
    public float multiplicacao(){
        return valor1 * valor2 * valor3;
    }
    
    public float divisao(){
        return (valor1 / valor2 / valor3);
    }
}


public class TesteMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculadora c1 = new Calculadora(23, 32, 54);
        System.out.println("A soma dos n�meros �: " + c1.soma());
        System.out.println("A subtra��o dos n�meros �: " + c1.subtracao());
        System.out.println("A multiplica��o dos n�meros �: " + c1.multiplicacao());
        System.out.println("A divis�o dos n�meros �: " + c1.divisao());
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual o resultado obtido? Por que não coloca as variáveis como parâmetros dos métodos ao invés de atributos das classes?

Comment: pq era dessa forma que estava especificado em um exercício, consegui rodar colocando "this.valor1 = valor1;' e assim com as outras variáveis no último construtor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa atribuir os valores passados como parâmetros nos construtores para os atributos privados da classe, assim os métodos funcionarão com sucesso. Da maneira que está no momento os métodos estão trabalhando com atributos vazios, logo, no método de soma, por exemplo, você está somando atributos sem valores.

A forma correta do terceiro construtor da classe seria:

```
 public Calculadora(float valor1, float valor2, float valor3){
        this.valor1 = valor1;
        this.valor2 = valor2;
        this.valor3 = valor3;
 }
```